# Akita 3 update: " Remove noop - use the of() observable." done what does that mean?

Tags: angular-akita, akita

In Akita I could

```
return noop
```

but after the upgrade they left this instruction as they removed noop as a breaking change;

> Remove noop - use the of() observable. done

what does that mean? an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`of()` observable is the equivalent of `noop` only that it's built-in in RxJS.